# How to load EditText fields with data fetched from server

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I've got an Activity where before showing the Text/EditText fields, I want to make a call to the server to get the details  and then `setText` of the fields based on the data gotten back from the server.

Below is what I'm doing but the fields don't seem to have the data fetched from the server. I think because I am calling an `AsyncTask` which gets run in the background and in the mean time the fields are shown to the user.

**Question**

How does android deal with this? What pattern should I be using?

This activity gets called from `MainActivity.java` like so:

```
Intent act = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MySecondActivity.class);
create.putExtra("theId", "138");
startActivity(create);
```

in `MySecondActivity.java` i do the following:

```
public class MySecondActivity extends SherlockActivity {

private EditText fieldOne;
private EditText fieldTwo;
private MyObj obj = new MyObj();
private int id;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shared_activity);
    fieldOne = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field_one);
    fieldTwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field_two);

    id = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("theId"));
    new FetchDetail().execute();

    //If I put the below two lines inside the AsyncTask then I get an error:
    //"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
    fieldOne.setText(obj.getOne()); //
    fieldTwo.setText(obj.getTwo()); //

}

class FetchDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    final RestAdapter restAdapter = new     
    RestAdapter.Builder().setServer("http://10.0.2.2:8080").build();
    final MyTaskService apiManager = restAdapter.create(MyTaskService.class);
    final MyObj obj = apiManager.getDetails(id);
    return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If I put the below two lines inside the AsyncTask then I get an error
```

Have these in `onPostExcute`

```
fieldOne.setText(obj.getOne()); 
fieldTwo.setText(obj.getTwo());
```

Do your background computation in `doInbackground`. Return result in `doInbackground`. The result of doInbackground computation is a pram to `onPostExecute`.

So you can update ui in `onPostExecute` which is invoked on the ui thread

Example:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
 // background computation
return "hello"; // return string
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) // string 
{
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     fieldOne.setText(result);   // hello is set to field One
}
```

For more info read the topic under The4Steps in the docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask has 3 methods to override:

1: onPreExecute

Executes on UI thread. So do what you want to do on UI before service call here(Ex: show a progress dialog).

2: doInBackground

Executes in background so perform long running task like fetching data from server.

3: onPostExecute

Executes on UI thread and gets called once doInBackground is completed you can process the result here and update the UI

Ex:

```
public class RestServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
}
```